# how to fix " invalid type (list) for variable 'cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4)' "

Tags: r, cbind

I am using poLCA package in R which has formula as Input parameter. In the documentation it says to pass  `cbind(dv1,dv2,dv3)~1` . Which I did and then it shows type (list ) error

I tried converting each parameter `y2 <-as.data.frame(Y2)` then inputed it, `y2` is a dataframe. But when I `cbind` all dataframe objects it is becoming a list.

```
Y1 <- data['CBM_Bin']  # input values to cbind
y1 <-as.data.frame(Y1)
Y2 <- data['FILE_MONTH']  # input values to cbind
y2 <-as.data.frame(Y2)
Y3 <- data['Client_Classification']  # input values to cbind
y3 <-as.data.frame(Y3)
Y4 <- data['FILE_QUARTER']  # input values to cbind
y4 <-as.data.frame(Y4)
X1 <- data['Our_Customer'] # input values to cbind
x1 <-as.data.frame(X1)
X2 <- data['Transhipment']  # input values to cbind
x2 <-as.data.frame(X2)
formula <- cbind.data.frame(Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4)~X1+X2  #This is showing error 
poLCA(formula, data, nclass = 2, maxiter = 1000, graphs = FALSE, 
     tol = 1e-10, na.rm = TRUE, probs.start = NULL, nrep = 1, 
     verbose = TRUE, calc.se = TRUE)
```

Actual Result:

> Error in model.frame.default(formula, data, na.action = NULL) : 
>     invalid type (list) for variable 'cbind(Y1, Y2, Y3, Y4)'

Expected Result is a dream to see

Comment: please a reproducible example

Comment: Did you mean to cbind your lowercase versions?

Comment: Not sure what's up with your syntax on the line you noted has the error. Why do you have `~` after making the data frame?